# Old Java project compatibility

Tags: java

I would like to ask a question about project compatibility. My thesis project is developed under JRE 1.6 and JDK 1.6 on windows vista and XP. The project use Java new socket. Today I try to run it on windows 8 (64bits) machine. The socket does not work. I configure the JRE and JDK to 1.6 later. It starts to work sometimes. The message can't be delivered by socket between different processes on a local machine. I also use a different version of eclipse. I have no clues now. Will the antivirus software be a factor too? Or related with IPv4 and IPv6?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Firewall configuration issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely not a Java compatibility issue.  The most likely explanations are (IMO) your application using the wrong addresses, or "firewalls", or (possibly) "access control".

It is also possible that you have specifically disabled IPv4 (or IPv6) on your new machine (or something) and you have coded the application to be IPv4-centric (or IPv6-centric).